# Does Juwel Cirax (ceramic biological filters) affect pH in the aquarium

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, filters, water-parameters

Currently the water in my aquarium is having a higher pH than I want. What I wonder is if the Cirax filter (and in general biological ceramic filters) affects the pH value (by increasing it, or if it is neutral towards the pH of the water?

I wonder this as I was thinking of adding a second one to my aquarium, but I am afraid of it increasing the pH even more.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it would affect pH in any way (and definitely would not raise it), but I can't find any source to back this up.

But about 2-3 months ago I added Cirax to my 180 litre tank (47 gallon, Juwel Vision with the stock Juwel filter). I regularly test my pH and did not measure any difference.

About 2 weeks ago I also added one of those blue Juwel sponges, and again I did not measure any differences.

If you're looking to lower the pH then there are a few other possibilities though.

- You could add chemicals to your water: http://www.sera.com.sg/fw_wateradjust.php
- You could add peat or peat moss to your filter: http://www.algone.com/adjust-ph-aquarium
- Catappa leaves: http://aquariadise.com/indian-almond-leaves/

But the biggest changes are probably achieved by adding CO<sub>2</sub>. JBL has a few CO<sub>2</sub> systems with a pH controller. You could configure your desired pH value, and it will automatically add CO<sub>2</sub> until that level is reached. But these systems are rather expensive.